# svn update over ssh tunnel update is failing

Tags: svn

I am using cygwin on Windows to update svn repo over ssh 
When I run svn update

```
hudson@b00 /cygdrive/c/Hudson/jobs/build/workspace/SVN/testSvn/Project 16.1
$  svn update svn+ssh://user@host/svn/rgbucwi/Project%2016.1 .
svn: E205000: Try 'svn help update' for more information
svn: E205000: 'svn+ssh://user@host/svn/rgbucwi/Project%2016.1' is not a local path
```

but

```
svn ls svn+ssh://user@host/svn/rgbucwi/Project%2016.1
```

Works fine, I maybe screwing up passing local path to svn update?

Anybody has any idea of why it is failing?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out `svn update` is sufficient after checking out using `svn+ssh` argument.